# How can I tell if ValidationSummary is triggered from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If ValidationSummary is triggered after postback, I would like to change the title of the page to say, "Error, the form is missing information to proceed".  I figured out how to change the title of the page, but don't know how to determine if validation is present or not from code behind. I'm not looking to see the ValidationSummary is valid, just interested if it's showing or not.

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you trying to validate that the form is filled out before they are allowed to submit it? Or are you trying to validate the code in the controller and respond on the page reload? Or are you asking how to tell what properties in our Model will use validation?

Comment: Hi Hasemeyer, thanks for the answer, but I'm not using MVC - just regular asp.net webpage (.aspx).  My webpage validates after you push the submit button.  I'm just using regular ValidationSummary control from Toolbox - which works fine.  I just want to be able to tell if that control is "on" or "off".  If there's a ValidationSummary showing on the page, I want to alter the title of page.

Comment: Ahh ok, I will remove my answer.

Comment: How many fields are you validating?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you have more than one input field with a required validator, and you want the ValidationSummary control to display a single, generic error message? Your questions is confusing; if the validation message is valid or not, can be plainly seen in the page?

Just set the HeaderText property to display the message you want and set the other controls as follows:

```
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="testValSummary" HeaderText="Oops" runat="server" />
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="nameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameReqVal" ControlToValidate="nameBox"
            Display="None" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="nameBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="nameReqVal2" ControlToValidate="nameBox2"
            Display="None" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="formButton" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
    </p>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {
            // Perform your logic here...
        }
    }
```